# Block sliding down hemisphere problem (harder) (need pleb Newtonian explanation)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

[image: Part (b)]

So this is from a pretty recent (freshman-level) physics university exam. Part (a) is relatively simple and standard for a freshman physics course. What I am finding much more difficult is part (b).

The question I have is, is there a way that this can be tackled with a reasonable amount of rigor under a framework of basic Newtonian mechanics?

(I elaborate further, below)

(note: the hemisphere is smooth)

Now, even in part (b), some of the equations aren't very difficult to construct, like an equation for circular motion in the hemisphere frame and a couple more to do with conservation of horizontal momentum but one also seems to need an equation that deals with energy conservation. I couldn't figure out how to construct an equation like that under the framework of normal Newtonian Mechanics that I was taught but looking at the solution I found that it should be:

*$\Delta G.P.E.(block)=\Delta K.E._{block} + \Delta K.E._{hemisphere}$*

Referring to the Work-Energy theorem, this seems to imply that (denoting the normal force between the hemisphere and block by $N$) the work done by $N$ on the hemisphere equals the -ve of the work done by $N$ on the block- I can't see how to prove this (although, the conservation formula does **feel** reasonably correct). My professor suggested that this would best be tackled using Lagrangian mechanics but also advised I might ask you guys (as my study into Lagrangian mechanics has not extended far beyond establishing some of the basic mathematical ideas) whether or not this could be done in the setting of basic Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: I agree with the Professor that lagrangian method is great for problems like this, are you familiar with the method?

Comment: No, like I've said, I've only had a look at some of the mathematics that goes in to establishing it.